# Invalid hook call in functional component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm using React Native and I get this error:
`Render Error Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...`

The problem is, there seems to be nothing wrong with the hook I use (useState), the error says I have a problem at this line:

`const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);`

I read the Rules of Hooks but I don't see anything wrong with this.

This is my component:

```
const GoalCard = (goal: IGoal) => { 
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const btnsOpacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const initialeCardHeight = goal.deadline != undefined ? 150 : 80
    const cardHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(initialeCardHeight)).current;
    
    
    const toggleCard = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        
        resizeCard();
        if(isOpen) {
            fadeOutBtns();
        } else {
            fadeInBtns();
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I call toggleCard (in the same file):

```
const renderDeadline = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.footer}>
            <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Icon name="time-outline" size={28} color="#A0A4BA" style={{marginRight: 4}}/>
                <Text style={styles.deadlineText}>Deadline</Text>
                <Text style={styles.dateText}>test</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleCard()}>
                <Icon name={isOpen ? "chevron-up-outline" : "chevron-down-outline"} size={21} color="#A0A4BA"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

`renderDeadline` component is inside `GoalCard`, and I saw in the Rules of Hooks that this might be the cause for this error.
So I tried removing it, and using the JSX of `renderDeadline` directly in `GoalCard` instead, but I got the same error (tried deleting the app and `npm run iOS` again, not just hot reload).

Comment: It's likely because of the multiple components in one file. Make sure you've just got one functional component in the file. I know you said you tried it but given the code looks OK that's what I'd have another look at.

Comment: @VladL Thanks, I tried removing unrelated (to the useState hook) functional components from the file, and reload but still got the same error.

Comment: Can you show the whole file?

Comment: @VladL Thanks, I deleted most of the file (each time I deleted a hook, I had an error with another hook) I will try and start over.